# Is there a way to install Windows from separate partition that boot with GRUB?

Tags: grub, windows-installation

There are some ways to install Linux. It can be installed from LiveCD, USB, bootstrap or separate partition that contains Linux installer. For Windows, I found (when googling) a way to install it directly from HardDrive. Basically, the concept is same (as far as I can understand) between Windows and Linux, that is fill the partition with the installer along side with boot required files. The two method can be read here:

- [Install Windows 7 from HDD](http://www.instructables.com/id/Install-Windows-7-without-USB-or-DVD-without-upgra/)
- [Install Ubuntu from HDD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromLinux)

Both methods involve similar method: copying installer files, make the partition bootable and register it to boot.

My Question is: is it possible to use GRUB to read Windows Installer that stored in separate partition? So the Windows installation option will show up in GRUB menu. It doesn't matter if GRUB menu will be gone after Windows installation is finished, it can be repaired later.

Answer (score 0):

Very doable. The method shown in my answer (here)[https://askubuntu.com/questions/116885/can-i-use-ubuntu-to-write-a-windows-7-iso-to-usb/363630#363630], while it focuses on using a usb flash drive, also works on partitions on a 'normal' hard drive. Just realize you cannot overwrite the installer partition during installation, as it must read from install.wim